# Can we use AJAXToolKit and Jquery in the same page

Tags: javascript

can we use AJAXToolKit and Jquery in the same page?

Say i have ScriptManage in that same page and i have also included the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. However, you may want to make use of [jQuery's `noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) statement.

I recommend putting your jQuery script directive in the ScriptManager, and use AJAXToolkit's `ToolkitScriptManager`, in place of `ScriptManager`.

Wrapping your `<Scripts>` in a `<CompositeScript>` tag, in conjunction with AJAXToolkit's `ToolkitScriptManager`, will combine all script files into 1 download at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery library, and virtually all of its plugins are constrained within the jQuery namespace. As a general rule, "global" objects are stored inside the jQuery namespace as well, so you shouldn't get a clash between jQuery and any other library (like Prototype, MooTools, or YUI).

That said, there is one caveat: By default, jQuery uses "$" as a shortcut for "jQuery"

However, you can override that default by calling jQuery.noConflict() at any point after jQuery and the other library have both loaded. For example:

```
   <script>
     jQuery.noConflict();

     // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("div").hide();
     });

     // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
     $('someid').hide();
   </script>
```

this way Query won't conflict with another library